# how to level-traverse while using `fs::filesystem` in c++

Tags: c++, vector, filesystems

By using fs::filesystem I can pre-order traverse Like below code

```
 for (const auto& file : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(paths))
        cout << file.path() << endl;
```

And, I found that `recursive_directory_iterator` only supports for pre-order.
Then How Can I use "level-order traversal" in c++? 
 I think I have to use `<vector>` . Any hints?

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) "*The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry is visited only once.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In loop you can push paths into `std::vector` after that loop sort this vector by `'/'` character count in paths.

Comment: Thanks. It's really easy and goooood idea Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to not use a recursive_directory_iterator.

Instead, use a non-recursive iterator with a queue. Start by pushing the root of the directories you want to iterate into the queue.

Then go into a loop:

- pop a directory name from the queue
- process that directory
- when you encounter a directory (that's *not* a symbolic link), push it into the queue
- repeat until the queue is empty

Comment: Thank you for answer. But How Can I check if directory has another directory?

Comment: Oh, sorry--when you dereference a `directory_iterator` you get a `directory_entry.` That, in turn, has an `is_directory` member.

Comment: Thanks. Then How can i implement post-order?

Comment: @Basicthings: to be sure of the traversal order, you'll need to implement the recursion yourself instead of using a recursive iterator. Other than that it's basically: for any node, process its child nodes, then process the current node.